# frechet manifolds book

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, frechet-manifold, books, textbook-recommendation

hi, does anyone know a good book or some lecture notes on the theory of frechet manifolds ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the book by Kriegl and Michor called "Convenient setting of global analysis" published by the AMS. It goes much beyond Fréchet and really gives a big panorama. However, it is not easy reading and requires really some work. But I guess that is due to the subject...

Comment: Also worth noting that it can be downloaded for free from the AMS bookstore.


Comment: @Andrew: yes that's nice. In fact, a lot of the marvelous books by Michor are available for free on his homepage. It's worth looking at...

Answer (score 11):

You could try

> Hamilton, Richard S. (1982). "The inverse function theorem of Nash and Moser". Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 7 (1): 65–222. doi:10.1090/S0273-0979-1982-15004-2

And there's a paper by Milnor on infinite dimensional Lie groups which could be useful.

Comment: It is available for free here: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.bams/1183549049